# Hide the highcharts tracker from image

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to hide the "highcharts-tracker" (clock) from the png/jpeg  exports?

I managed to hide it from the guage chart itself by using $("highChartsGuageId").find('.highcharts-tracker').hide();

Not sure whether this is possible or not.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chartOptions to configure exported chart.

```
exporting:{
        chartOptions:{
            plotOptions:{
                gauge:{
                    dial:{
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                    },
                    pivot:{
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/c3eL785x/